# Selenium NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, selenium

I am getting the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element
 (Session info: chrome=39.0.2171.95)
```

From the looks of the error message it says that it couldnt find such element.
So i added a wait until the element appears.
The funny thing is that the error occurs on the line driver.findElement which means that the wait was able to find the element.

The question is obviously why is selenium not able to find the element.

At first i thought it was because of using a variable in the string

```
driver.findElement(By.id("_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_eoiSectionSummary_individualRepeater__ctl0_sectionRepeater__ct" + i + "_isCompleteLabel")).getText();
```

So i tried to store the string somewhere and then findElement with it.
As you see in the code below i have tried using print to verify that the string is the same as the one in the web. And they do match.

Im currently out of ideas now. Please help. Please let me know if you need any other information

```
public int verifyCompletion() {

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_eoiSectionSummary_individualRepeater__ctl0_sectionRepeater__ctl0_isCompleteLabel")));
    int uncompletedCounter = 0;

    for (int i = 10; i < 20; i++) {
        String text  = "_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_eoiSectionSummary_individualRepeater__ctl0_sectionRepeater__ct" + i + "_isCompleteLabel";
         driver.findElement(By.id(text)).getText();

        System.out.println(text);

        boolean sectionCompleted =text.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes");
        if (!sectionCompleted) {
            uncompletedCounter++;
        }

    }
    return uncompletedCounter;


}
```

Comment: Do you know for sure 20 elements exist on that page? and Just wondering why are you start looping from 10?

Comment: Hi there, there will always be 9 Elements on that page. ct10 to ct19. Thats why i started looping from 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a small bug in your selector. You are not parameterizing the selector correctly. I am not sure if it a very efficient way to handle this scenario though.

```
String selector  = "_ctl" + i + "_ContentPlaceHolder1_eoiSectionSummary_individualRepeater__ctl" + i + "_sectionRepeater__ctl" + i + "_isCompleteLabel";
```

**Edit: more precise code should look like this:**

```
public int verifyCompletion() {
    int uncompletedCounter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        String selector  = "_ctl" + i + "_ContentPlaceHolder1_eoiSectionSummary_individualRepeater__ctl" + i + "_sectionRepeater__ctl" + i + "_isCompleteLabel";
        (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id(selector)));
        String elementText = driver.findElement(By.id(selector)).getText();

        System.out.println(selector);
        System.out.println(elementText);

        boolean sectionCompleted =text.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes");
        if (!sectionCompleted) {
            uncompletedCounter++;
        }
    }
    return uncompletedCounter;
}
```

Comment: Hi there, Thanks for your Comment.How ever only the last ct is incremented. So they should all be ct10 expect for the last one.

Comment: You are welcome. If I were you I would use `List<WebElement> el = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("your selector to grab the list of expected elements"));` and then loop through and print the text. That's cleaner. If you need help with the selector provide me the html and I would try to help. And, I think the above code solved your issue

Comment: Hi There, I have tried the above method and it doesn't work. It still unable to find the element. The only way it will find the element is by hard coding the string in like.       `driver.findElement(By.id("_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_eoiSectionSummary_individualRepeater__ctl0_sectionRepeater__ctl0_isCompleteLabel")).getText();` If i use anything else it wont be able to locate the element.

Comment: I wonder if `ctl0` is 'L(l)' or `One(1)` I am pretty convinced that  it is 'l'(L) not One `1`

Comment: if it is an `l` the selector should look like `"_ctl" + i + "_ContentPlaceHolder1_eoiSectionSummary_individualRepeater__ctl" + i + "_sectionRepeater__ctl" + i + "_isCompleteLabel";` and start looping from `0` by having `i=0`

Comment: Its 1. I have copy and paste the String. I have had a senior Dev helping me have a look at the code. He thinks that its due to some understanding of Selenium, he says that its definitely not something to do with syntax.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68692/discussion-between-saifur-and-the-java-noob).

Comment: Currently The Question is updated to why `driver.findElement(By.id("_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_eoiSectionSummary_individualRepeater__ctl0_sectionRepeater__ctl0_isCompleteLabel")).getText()` works and why  `String element = "_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_eoiSectionSummary_individualRepeater__ctl0_sectionRepeater__ct" + i + "_isCompleteLabel"; WebElement ele =  driver.findElement(By.id(element));` doesnt